# How to checkout commit from bare repository into specified directory

Tags: git

I have a directory with multiple *.git bare repositories. I need to checkout files from a specified repository for a specified commit reference (symbolic or SHA-1) into a specified directory. I mean just a working tree snapshot, i.e. without git metadata. How can I do that without locking the repository (i.e. this operation should be reentrant)?

Comment: Use `git archive`, pipe the output to `tar -xf -`?

Comment: This really looks like a crutch, I don't believe there's no clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify [`--git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt):

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/bare/repo.git --work-tree=/path/to/worktree checkout "$commit" -- .
```

[`--work-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt) is required for the command to work with a bare repository.

**NB** This will overwrite any files that you might have in the work tree directory without warning and without a way to recover!

Comment: I get the following error: "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree".

Comment: @ababo it works for me (Git 2.31.0). You might need to specify the directory for checkout explicitely, I've updated my answer on that part

Comment: Did you mean that /path/to/worktree is just an empty dir? Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ababo Yes, /path/to/dir is an empty directory (it can also contain files, but they could be overwritten by checkout)

Comment: Watch out with this method: Git will update the index, and use the index to decide what to update, in the specified working tree. If the index exists and describes a *different* working tree, the result can be very poor.

Comment: Are you sure your repo is bare? Doesn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @ababo interesting, it does not work with bare repositories, you are right. As soon as the `core.bare` config option is enabled, the error will appear. In this case, use torek's suggestion from the comment: `git archive` + `tar`

Comment: @ababo I troubleshooted a bit, and for bare repositories, you must provide the `--work-tree` option.

Comment: @knittl Can you share a command example? Asking because I got the same error when used this option as well.

Comment: @knittl I don't have a working tree (and would prefer to not to make it), what should I pass?

Comment: @ababo what do you mean? Isn't your question "how to checkout a commit into a directory"? That directory's path will be the argument to the work tree option. The command example is already in my answer (which I have verified to work with a bare repository).

Comment: @knittl Please update your answer with more concrete example. Let's say we have /a/b/c.git bare repo and I need to checkout master into /d/e/f. Please share an exact command to do that. Thank you!

Comment: @ababo replace each path in my example with your values: `git --git-dir=/a/b/c.git --work-tree=/d/e/f master -- .` – it's exactly the command from the answer (both paths replaced with different values and "$commit" substituted with master)